# CanonicalDocFlowSegment is blank or null

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am facing this Issue, when the order is placed in hybris and sent to crm in backend (i checked the businessprocess flow in backoffice the status is OK).

[image]
2020-12-11 14:30:08,669 [DEBUG] [c.h.d.c.i.CompositionChainRunnerStrategy] Integration Key generation for canonical item CanonicalItem{status=ERROR, dataPool=DataHubPoolEntity{id=9306, name=SAPORDER_OUTBOUND_POOL}, fields={precedingDocumentId=null, orderId=**0006200128**}} failed.
com.hybris.datahub.composition.key.**IncompleteKeyException**: **Value for attribute precedingDocumentId of canonical item CanonicalDocFlowSegment is blank or null**.

In tomcat server, after this IncompleteKeyException, i could see Idoc's are generated in console for the above (**0006200128**)orderId.

So Question is, what exactly "canonical item CanonicalDocFlowSegment is blank or null" mean and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue related to precedingDocumentId of canonical item CanonicalDocFlowSegment is blank or null: resolved by removing the sapreturnorders related jars in the library.

These jars is mainly required in case of return order.

i.e., all three jars for sapreturnorder (raw, canonical and target) from tomcat library.

After removing jars follow the below steps:
1.restart the catalina server(tomcat).
2.do InitialLoad from backoffice.

For more details refer:https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=precedingDocumentID&state=PRODUCTION&language=en-US&format=standard,html,pdf,others